# Replace a unknown string between two known string in an minified js file using sed

Tags: json, sed

I have a minified js file, which contains some server url, I need to change that url based with a url from another file.

`{serverUrl:"existingUrl"}`

The url which needs to be changed is unknown, but I do know that it's part of a JS object, So I have the key.

I have the following code, which seems to be doing most of the required part, but its also removing huge chunk of code from the JS file, which is not what I want.

```
systemAuthUrl="someurl"
prefix='serverUrl:"'
suffix='"'

find ./prod/build/js/ -type f -name "bundle.*.js" -exec sed -i "s#$prefix.*$suffix#$prefix$systemAuthUrl$suffix#g" {} \;
```

How can I modify the above command to only replace the string between prefix and suffix with variable systemAuthUrl

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matches is `sed` are greedy, which means it will match everything until the last `"` in your file.

You may replace `.*` with `[^\"]+` so that it matches anything but the quotation mark.

Comment: doesn't work for me, not replacing anything


`
prefix='serverUrl:"'
seperator='[^"]+'
suffix='"'

find ./export/js/ -type f -name "bundle.*.js" -exec sed -i "s#$prefix$seperator$suffix#$prefix$systemAuthUrl$suffix#g" {} \;
`

Comment: It is not a separator. It is the body of your string: 
"s#$prefix[^\"]+$suffix#$prefix$systemAuthUrl$suffix#g"